# Traction characteristic of the three phase induction motor

Tags: motor, control, induction-motor

I have found a datasheet for a three phase induction motor intended for the traction applications. Among other information there was a below given traction characteristic
[image]. Unfortunately I am not able to provide a hyperlink here.

I have done a comparison between this traction characteristic and the capability curve of the induction motor given in the [Electric Motor Control book](https://shop.elsevier.com/books/electric-motor-control/kim/978-0-12-812138-2) on page 143

[image]

and several questions arose in my mind

1. Why the traction characteristic includes both the torque and the stator current
   waveform?
2. Why the stator current in the traction characteristic has such complicated waveform
   which additionaly doesn't correspond with the torque waveform?
3. Why the stator voltage achieves its limit at different speed then the field weakening
   region starts?
4. It is known fact that the torque capability depends on the dc link voltage of the
   voltage source inverter used for the motor control. In case the dc link voltage is less
   than nominal value the field weakening region starts at lower speed. Is the same true
   also for the current curve?
5. Let's say I have a control software implementing the field oriented control of the three
   phase induction machine. How can I integrate such traction characteristic into the
   control algorithm?

Comment: Please provide hyperlinks for the sources of the pictures.

Comment: add the hyperlinks to the question... do not write a comment